# iOS 7 Local notifications with no sound by default

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7, uilocalnotification

When I run the app on my iOS 7 device, the app doesn't appear on the device notifications settings and doesn't sounds when a notification is being fires. Only after the first notification is being fired, I can see my app under the list of the notification settings with sounds turned off.

1. Why doesn't the app show in the notifications list initially?
2. Why are the sounds turned off by default?

On iOS 5&6 I don't have these problems. These are local notifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like iOS 7.0.3 includes a fix for that.

Comment: I've got iOS 7.0.4 and I'm still seeing sound off by default.

Comment: Me too.Please help mme

Comment: See my answer above. perfect solution

Answer (score 1):

Have you set the applicationIconBadgeNumber in "- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions"? Comment this code, and try again.....I don't why, but I got the same problem. After I commented this line, my app works correctly.

Comment: Ok, I must admit that at first I completely ignored this answer, because, I mean, c'mon, WTF!?! But I got desperate and just tried it. It's working! Oh my.

Comment: I'm facing this problem on ios7.0.4 on iphone4 but i done above trick its not working, please assist me....

Answer (score 0):

I got this same problem. What i found out was, i have a piece of code that caused this all along.

In my AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, i have implemented:

```
//remove this if you have it
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber: 0]; //to reset the badge everytime the app loads
```

So what i did, I removed that code & redeploy the app. Now it has ON default value in Notification Center.

Phew.

Answer (score -1):

Hmm,
Interestingly, I changed the order of

notification.SoundName = UILocalNotification.DefaultSoundName;
notification.ApplicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

to

notification.ApplicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
notification.SoundName = UILocalNotification.DefaultSoundName;

and it works now. When the app is running in background, the local notification fires and plays the default notification sound.